# What is the correct syntax to set Signal to noise (SNR) offset or target noise margin in ZyXel AMG1202 t10b

Tags: linux, networking, command-line, router, wan

I tried to find CLI reference for my router (ZyXel AMG1202 t10b) but couldn't find it on their website (there is for older and newer models but not for this one) I already contacted their support but they didn't answer. So i don't know how to use commands to set this property. I connected with telnet to the modem and found many commands but there is no syntax help. It also doesn't show errors when i type something wrong. All lists of commands that i found:[commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iDJj.png)
The one i probably need is "wan" command (in usr/bin)
That command is used in older models:

```
wan adsl targetnoise <target_noise_margin>
```

Description:
Set the target noise margin.target noise margin:-31 ~ 32.

```
wan adsl snroffset
```

Description:
Set snr offset. usage: set snr offset (offset(db)*512) curre
nt 
value:0

I tried both of these commands and they had no effect on my router.Does anyone know the correct syntax for this command or is there any way to find out? I wonder if i can download binary for this command and decompile it to see how it works. (Not sure how can i download this command or do i have to download everything because i'm not familiar with linux or busybox)

Comment: I think this is an XY problem which is frowned upon here... What is the actual problem your having? These values generally should not be messed with and may be configured by ISP in their negotiation phase of the ADSL modem connection setup

Comment: @acejavelin I want to adjust these values to get more download and upload speed if i can ( if my connection is stable enough )

Comment: It will maybe work maybe not , still want to try it.

Comment: Adjusting these values will not change your data speeds, your speeds are limited by your carrier or line quality.

Comment: @acejavelin thats what i thought before, but then i saw this post: http://corz.org/network/routers/Zyxel_AMG1302-T10B/
and i searched it on google and many people say that their internet speed has increased when they done this . Also this website claims that too: http://www.increasebroadbandspeed.co.uk/SNR-tweak

I'm not sure if it's true, thats why i want to test it.

Comment: @acejavelin also they say it's possible to make your connection more stable if you reduce SNR.

Comment: this was true years ago with a few carriers DSLAMs, but all major manufacturers have patched this so regardless of your settings, the DSLAM will not allow your bit rate speed to exceed their defined parameters. If your not experiencing significant refrains, it wouldn't have any effect,  if you are then your carrier should correct the line problem. Note the article you linked, not all modems are capable of what your asking. Try Googling Zyxel (model) CLI reference, or a similar ADSL modem model

Comment: @acejavelin Already tried that, they don't have cli reference for this model for some reason, and this one should have this capability. I guess i will try with reverse engineering. It's possible that my ISP didn't patch this because their equipment is old and they don't have much knowledge in this field

Comment: possible... Try a different Zyxel ADSL model, they share the a common CLI.